# Error while importing images to Google storage in Cloud AutoML Vision

Tags: google-apis-explorer, automl, google-cloud-automl

I am using the google AutoML vision api object detection option in google console.When I try to upload the images to google storage to train the model, I am getting "Failed to import" error.

I have tried using the csv file option as well but the same error persists.

Since I am using the object detection model in google console, so it does not require to write any code.

The expected result is that the images are imported successfully so that I can move to next step to train my model.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem when upload a dataset from cloud storage (Select a CSV file on Cloud Storage) it shows this error message.

[Failed to import data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejEHf.png)

However, I checked the IMAGES section and the dataset was there, so it was successfully uploaded regardless the error message (you can ignore it).